# Running a script via module vs script mode in the BGE

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

When a script is run via *Script* mode through the *Python Controller* there is no need to have `import bge` in the script.
Why does running a script via *Module* mode require importing bge?

[Documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:/Tutorials/Game_Engine/ScriptMode_vs_ModuleMode) on the blender wiki of the differences between script and module modes.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10769/599

Answer (score 2):

> Why does running a script via Module mode require importing bge?

Because the import statement is the proper way of writing Python code.

The auto-import within script mode is a dirty shortcut. It is still there for backward compatibility. But it is no good design.

### Pro

- You always need it to access the the BGE context anyway. 
  (In module mode you do not really need it as you can get access via function arguments.)
- Bge is not a real Python module. It is a wrapper around the BGE native code.

### Contra

- It violates the Python convention to show where objects are coming from (defined by the code or imported from other modules)
- It hides the fact that this module is imported at all. So a reader will never see an explicit assignment to **bge**.
- The bge module should behave like regular Python modules, so it should be imported as any other Python module too.

I strongly suggest to add the import statement in script mode too and ignore the auto-import.

I hope it helps

Comment: ok, so why does `bge` get auto imported when run as a script, but not when run as a module?

Comment: I can't tell the reasons, because I do not know them. The auto-import was there as I met the BGE the first time (~2.37). The module was called GameLogic at that time and only script mode was available.