# How do I convert the module to script?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

Change my python type from Module to Script?
In Blender #game engine

[image]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21403/running-a-script-via-module-vs-script-mode-in-the-bge  and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10769/what-is-the-difference-between-module-and-script-execution-methods-in-the-game-e IMO would use module.  Can you elaborate on why you wish to change?  _It will involve editing the script, in which case post the script_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these two lines at the end of the script:

```
cont = logic.getCurrentController()
main(cont)
```

The module mode calls specifically the function `main` through the entry point on the controller, while in the script mode you have to explicitly call the main function on the script. As the `main` function needs the controller reference, you get the controller and pass to it.

That's how you use a module as a script, however I would seriously recommend you to stick with the module mode: the script mode is A LOT slower than the module mode (as it is parsed at runtime) and the module mode provides much better options on code editing and organization.

Comment: Thank you very much!