# BGE: Refer to keyboard event boolean problem

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

Got this strange little issue:
I've got a separate module, besides variables such as the player object and animation functions there is also the boolean variable for the <kbd>W</kbd> key.

```
w_active = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == bge.logic.keyboard.events[bge.events.WKEY]
```

Now when I import it from the module to another script and go like:

```
if w_active:
   run_animation()
```

It won't play it but when I don't use the variable and write the `bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE = bge.logic.keyboard.events(bge.events.WKEY)` right after the `if` it does work.

I also checked it out with `print(w_active)` it seems the problem is that the boolean stays on `False` even when I press the <kbd>W</kbd> key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to because the [module will only be executed once](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10769/599). Variables assigned directly inside the module will retain their initial value and won't be re-evaluated when accessed later.

To re-evaluate a variable, define it inside a function and call the function from wherever you want to access the current value of the variable.

For example, in the module you might create a function to return True if the <kbd>W</kbd> key is pressed:

```
import bge

def is_w_active():
    return(bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == bge.logic.keyboard.events[bge.events.WKEY])
```

Then when this is called from a script (or anywhere else) like so:

```
import bge, keyboardmodule

print(keyboardmodule.is_w_active())
```

it will return True or False accordingly.

[image]