# Pyserial and Arduino every Time new Connect problem

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I have a potentiometer and I want this to change the location of my cube. My script run is on the cube, connected to an "Always" actuator with True Toggle.

My problem is this line:

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM6',9600, timeout=1)
```

The script throws an error: `ser` is not defined

This line is read every Time, so my arduino must connect every Time. I need to perform a new connect every second, but I want float move.

So I try this, because the serial line is only executed once:

```
import serial
import time
import bge
import bpy

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
ob = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects["Cube"]
own = cont.owner
PSerial=own['SerialVerbunden']

print (PSerial)
if (PSerial==False):
    ser = serial.Serial('COM6',9600, timeout=1)
    time.sleep(1)
    count = 0
    own['SerialVerbunden']=True




a = int(ser.readline().strip())
print (a)
count = count + 1
scene.worldPosition = [a, 0, 0]
ob.location = scene.worldPosition
ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=count)
```

The script throws the error mentioned above: `ser` is not defined.

Yes this is true, because it is loading and at the end it forgets.
The variable `count` have the same problem. It can't count.
But how I can solve it?
If I write a while loop, so I cant see my cube is moving, Blender freezes.

Comment: I suspect your if block may not be getting executed, as it doesn't look like `PSerial` is ever `False`. If you put a print statement inside the if, does it print?

Comment: I've edited your question in an attempt to make it easier to understand. If I've misinterpreted anything, please don't hesitate to [edit] it yourself or [roll back](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing) my edits. Thanks :) That said, are you trying re-establish the serial connection once a second? Or just once? The latter seems more likely, but I'm afraid I can't quite tell what you meant.

Comment: this is correct, my english is only bad ^^ with the PSerial Variable i would like to solve my problem, but i get more problems(ser is not defined). 
If this script is re-played, then probably all are variable away. Therefore my script does not work, but I want to show with what I plan. By putting the "ser variable", pyserial connects with my Arduino. This requires 1 second. That's why I had to use time.sleep (1). but I want to bypass that and would like to see at least 25 frames per second.

If I use a While Loop, then Blender unresponsive and I can not finish the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest you separate connecting from communication. Do not forget you should execute a closing when the connection is not needed anymore.

Basically you need this three operations in this order over multiple frames:

- establish a connection
- communicate (receive/send) via connection
- close connection [which seams not to apply at serial)

I suggest to implement it that way:

```
import serial
import bge

INTERNAL_PROPERTY_CONNECTION = "_connection"

listener = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner

connection = listener.get(INTERNAL_PROPERTY_CONNECTION)
if not connection:
    connection = serial.Serial('COM6',9600, timeout=0)
    listener[INTERNAL_PROPERTY_CONNECTION] = connection

# your communciation
a = int(connection.readline().strip())
cube = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects["Cube"]
cube.worldPosition.x = a
```

Comment: Your script works, but has very strong deceleration and the Cube trembles.
But with Errors
dj-eki.de/Dateien/StackExchange/blendergamefehler2.jpg

Comment: It looks like a conversion problem coming from int(..) which is something you need to solve by yourself. It is just a copy from your original code. I can't tell what serial is providing to you at that stage.

Comment: I note that the data are read faster than output. I have tried several scripts in my arduino. 1. Serial.println without delay. 2. Serial.println with delay (1000). So 1 second. at 1 second of delay it writes about 10 seconds, the same number. It reads a lot more than it can Output.

Comment: I have this Output dj-eki.de/Dateien/StackExchange/blendergamefehler3.jpg I marked some red. Is this blank line my problem?

Comment: This Output is coming from a = connection.readline().decode()

Comment: ur Code Works, thx, but i dont understand this script. But i have found a easier solution. My Problem was only a wrong code from arduino. too short delay. My Arduino was faster than Blender :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have no arduino to test with at the moment, but I did something quite similar in the past.

As you've discovered, `time.sleep()` will freeze the execution of the entire game engine, rather than just the script. Instead of sleeping or running in a loop (don't forget that the game engine is calling our script repeatedly anyway, so in a sense we're already in a loop), try something like this:

```
import serial

# the bge passes the current controller in as the first argument for us, we'll call it "cont"
def receive(cont): 
    # get current gameobject
    own = cont.owner

    # check for our "reminder property":
    if "ser_init" not in own: 
        # code in here is only run once
        ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
        # store a property to remind us later if we've already run the above code
        own["ser_init"] = True 

    # everything else will be executed every logic tic like normal:

    # get data (this is how I was reading in data for my project, you might do it differently)
    data = ser.readline().decode()
    # do something with data
    print(data)
```

I've put it in a function `receive()` so that it can be called by a [module execution controller](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13964/599):

[image]
<sup>Note the `.py` extension on the script name. The script won't be executed without it!</sup>

Comment: @DjEKI Hm.. I suspect there might be an error earlier on. Do you get output when running *without* true level triggering enabled?

Comment: I can see a Number as Output, without error

Comment: I Get a number and a empty line, how like the post from Monster

Comment: Is that number coming from the serial output? If you remove the print statement, is it still there?

Comment: I get the same Error. Monster has a good answere, but have only a decode problem, i think.

Comment: But, if i delete data = ser.readline().decode() i get no error.

Comment: Ty for your help with module. I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by "gandalf3" Help. His script was not working, but showed me the function of modules, so that I could be solved it myself thank you! Monster Script also works, but the fault lay with me. Nevertheless, I did not understand his script. My mistake was in Monster script: The output was a huge delay. The Arduino had a too short delay "delay (1)". My Arduino was faster than Blender :) I changed it to "delay (25)". Now I can turn the potentiometer and without delay.

My Script works: This script runs in Module.

```
import serial


ser = serial.Serial('COM6',9600)

def funktion():
    print (ser.readline().decode())
```