# Commands from serial port to blender controls

Tags: python, add-on, operator

I'd like to make some extra keyboard on Arduino to send some commands to Blender. Some commands just duplicating existing shortcuts, some of them I need to start custom python scripts during manipulating scenes. I know about modal operator that allows to make something like that, when some event happens. Mouse move or push a button events. Main question is: is it possible not to use any triggers to listen commands from serial and execute them while receiving?

Comment: does [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63272/935) help?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately there is the same "Modal Operator" I mentioned. Game Engine is also not the solution as far as I know it purposes.